# B2B application: users has its own users

Tags: database-design, erd, application-design, oracle-xe, physical-design

B2B Scenario I am trying is that: 
The following Roles exists in the system:

1. Super Admin
2. Super Admin Staff
3. Owner (client)
4. Admin (owner i.e. client and creates admin to define sales counters)
5. Sales Counters

That means there are users who'll create their own sub users e.g. 
**[FLAG-A]** ROLE "SUPER ADMIN" creates a ROLE "Owner" and "OWNER" creates its own sub users ROLES i.e. "ADMN" & "SALES COUNTER".

Each role obviously has its info to login to the system

I tried to design database as following:

[image]

In this diagram I am assuming that main user creates sub user that in my view many to many relationship so I have to add table between them as "USER_PERSON".

Problem is to set "WHO CREATED USER" in the system. I mean which user has created sub user as described in **[FLAG-A]**

Please check this diagram
[image]

Comment: your design is quite confusing, the arrows gpfor example from user permosssission_container where exactly? you have sub_users anuseres as brdige table, but bioth contain mostly the same columns, so why have you 2 of them?

Comment: @nbk regarding permissions --> user_permission table lists all permissions whereas user_permission_container has permissions that are assigned to the user. By the way its not real problem that I asked here. I have bridge table due to "many to many" relationship

Comment: What's the difference between user role and category?

Comment: @mustaccio category is business type e.g. Travel agent, Hotel etc. whereas role is like super admin, admin, sales counter etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is unnecessarily complicated. Your situation boils down to this:

- You have users (also persons), with their corresponding attributes, including login credentials and such, but also status and last login date.
- A user (person) can have one (or more?) role(s).
- A role has one or more permissions.
- A user can be created by one other user, so the user's creator is among the user's attributes.

So, I'd model three entities:

1. User (with all the properties), with a self-reference to the user's creator.
2. Role, with a many-to-many relationship to User.
3. Permission, with a many-to-one (or many-to-many) relationship to Role.

That's it.

Comment: `A user (person) can have one (or more?) role(s).` This is not true. A user has its own sub users not roles

Comment: I updated my question and added a new diagram. Is that seems near to my requirements?